# Jquery select first parent of <td> tag in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery V1.11.1 in my application. I have a HTML table which looks like this:

```
<table id="permissions">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>Administrators</th>
        <th>Moderators</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="aco">controllers/users/display</th>
        <td class="permission">Allowed</td>
        <td class="permission">Denied</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When you click on "Allowed" or "Denied" I want to select the TH tag which contains the ACO.

I thought this would do it, but it doesnt. `$(this).parent('th').text();`

What is the best way to select the TH tag using Jquery in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('th.aco').text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ump5/1/)

or

```
$(this).siblings('th.aco').text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U29SG/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.siblings()` in jquery

```
   $(this).siblings('th.aco').text();
```

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I don't see `parent()` in this answer.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr actually he edited the answer. His initial answer was something like $(this).closest("th")

Comment: Ohh.. I don't see the edited history so I assumed that you wanted to post this comment on OP question.  I agree that if a post is edited within few seconds,  history is not maintained(I don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.permission').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.aco').text();
})
```

or if more than one siblings has this class `.aco`

```
$('.permission').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('th.aco').text();
})
```

will select the `th` that is parallel to the clicked `td` and display it's text.  You can perform a different function on selected `th` instead of `.text()`.